# Showing records in multiple rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display my records in multiple rows.

**Ex:** I am have 10 records and I want to show these records as 3 records in one row, other 3 records in another row and so on.

Comment: When you say a row do you mean a table row?

Comment: Use Table in HTML..... it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can display using html

```
 <tr> </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<table>
<% 
rowCount = 0
@recordsList = Modal.find(:all)
   @recordsList.each do |rec|

      #this will use to make new row.
      if rowCount%3==0
%>
      <tr>
<%    end %>
         <!-- add your records here -->
         <td><%= rec.recordfield %></td>
<%
      rowCount = rowCount + 1

      end
   end
%>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your solution

Use [in-groups-of](http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of)

**For example**

```
<table>
  <% @tasks.in_groups_of(4, false) do |row_tasks| %>
    <tr>
      <% for task in row_tasks %>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**Source** :

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of
2. http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have @articles that has 10 articles
then so something like

```
<div class="articles">
 <% @articles.each_with_index do |article, article_index|%>
    <div class="article" style="float:left">
      <%=article.name%>
    </div>
    <% if (article_index+1) % 3 == 0%>
    <br/> <!-- Or write a div and clear it -->
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```